# Chapter 1, Exercise 12 in Brian Hall's Lie groups, Lie algebras, and representations

Tags: matrices, group-theory, lie-groups, general-linear-group

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are invertible $n \times n$ matrices. Show that there are only finitely many complex
numbers $\lambda$ for which $\text{det}( \lambda A + (1-\lambda)B) = 0$. Show that there exists a continuous path $A(t)$ of the form $A(t) = \lambda(t) A + (1 - \lambda (t)) B$ connecting A to B and such that $A(t)$ lies in $GL(n; \mathbb{C})$. Here, $λ(t)$ is a
continuous path in the plane with $λ(0) = 0$ and $λ(1) = 1$.

I solved the first part:
Since $A$ and $B$ are invertible: $\text{det}( \lambda A + (1-\lambda)B) = 0$ is a non zero polynomial of degree at most n with complex coefficients, so, by the fundamental theorem of algebra, this polynomial have at most n complex zeroes. For the second part I was thinking: first of all $A(t): t \in [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$, is continuous because $\lambda(t)$ is continuous. Since $\text{det}(A(0)) = \text{det}(B) \neq 0$ and $\text{det}(A(1)) = \text{det}(A) \neq 0$ we can always find in the complex plane a continuous path $\lambda(t)$ with $λ(0) = 0$ and $λ(1) = 1$ that avoids the zero $\forall t \in (0,1)$. Is my proof correct?

Comment: The line '$\mathrm{det}(A(t))$ is zero at only atmost $n$ points in the interval $(0,1)$' is not necessary. Yes, your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Thanks, now i was thinking, if the determinant of A and B have opposite sign, isn't it a problem?

Comment: They are complex matrices. They have complex determinants.

Comment: You're right thanks.

Comment: Whether or not the proof is "correct" may depend on the intended audience, especially as the last sentence seems to merely assert that you can find a path.  If I was grading this proof for a class, I'd probably take off a few points for lack of detail.  If I was putting this kind of argument in a paper to be submitted to a journal, I'd probably have even fewer details ;-)

Comment: Umm ok, i understood your point, how can I improve it? I have to explain the proof to my professor. In particular what how can I improve the last part?

Comment: You might include a proof that there is a continuous path from $0$ to $1$ that avoids the  finitely many "bad" values of $\lambda$. (This is where it's important to have $\mathbb C$ and not just $\mathbb R$.)

Comment: I have modified something.